# come to extinct or come to extinction?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct "come to extinct" or "come to extinction"?

I want to talk about Hawaiian papaya that had been in danger of extinction but was saved. Can I use this sentence "The infection caused Hawaiian papaya to come nearly to extinct/extinction"?

Comment: "To" occurs in only two syntactic frames in English: followed by a verb (eg _to die out_) and followed by a noun phrase (eg _to extinction_, _to the bitter end_). "Extinct" is an adjective, (Some adjectives can be used as nouns, but "extinct" is not one of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use "to go extinct".

While less common, one could also use:

- to come to extinction
- to face extinction
- to be driven into extinction (by something)
- to fall into extinction

Slightly rephrasing your sentence: "The infection caused Hawaiian papaya to come close to extinction."